# MSComCtl2.DTPicker of control ... was not a loaded control class

Tags: windows-7, logging, dll

I am attempting to load a project from Visual Source Safe onto my Windows 7 32-bit machine in Visual Studio 6.0.

Everything is successful except for an error that occurs in finding this "MSComCtl2 DLL"

it creates a log file with the name of each form that uses a date-time picker. The log file states:

> MSComCtl2.DTPicker of control ...  was not a loaded control class

with the name of the variable name of the control in place of the ellipsis.

I thought it would be a simple fix to just download or register the MSComCtl2 DLL but I cannot find it anywhere.

I tried downloading and applying the Common Controls DLL (Platform SDK
Redistributable) and http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24417 but it made no difference...

What should I try next?

Comment: You seem to have copied the shortened text of the link and not the actual URL, so it's naturally broken. Anyway, try installing [this](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24417) (right-click and run it as admin) and see if it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I bet you have Visual Studio 2010 or something installed. The .Net framework causes some conflicts. You are going to have to uninstall 1 or the other.

Answer (score -1):

I've solved the problem this way:

Search for the  "MSComCtl2 DLL" and copy over the same path as the .vbp project.
Then try to re-open the project.

If this fail, register the file (in that path) usign RegSvr32.

Work for me!